# How can I get a Group By to show me a 0 if no rows match?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: Phrase and PhraseCategory

They are linked with `Phrase.CategoryId` == `PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT              NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhraseCategory] (
    [PhraseCategoryShortId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name]                  VARCHAR (100)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseCategoryShortId] ASC)
);
```

Can someone help give me some advice on how I can join these so that I get a report looking like this:

```
PhraseCategory.Name        Qty
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT PhraseCategory.name, count(*) AS qty
  FROM Phrase
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PhraseCategory
    ON Phrase.CategoryId = PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId
 GROUP BY PhraseCategory.name
 ORDER BY PhraseCategory.name
```

The problem for me is that I want it to show the Phrase Category name and a 0 if there are no rows with that category. So far I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the `LEFT JOIN` backwards:

```
SELECT pc.name, count(p.CategoryId) AS qty
FROM PhraseCategory pc LEFT JOIN
     Phrase p
     ON p.CategoryId = pc.PhraseCategoryShortId
GROUP BY pc.name
ORDER BY pc.name;
```

You seem to want everything in `PhraseCategory`, so it should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.  Also note that the `COUNT()` changed, so it counts the matches in the second table (this is how it returns `0`).

Answer (score 1):

Your join is in the wrong order, and you need to count only the records in Phrase, not both tables:

```
SELECT PhraseCategory.name, count(Phrase.*) AS qty
  FROM PhraseCategory
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Phrase
    ON Phrase.CategoryId = PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId
 GROUP BY PhraseCategory.name
 ORDER BY PhraseCategory.name
```

Of course, you could change the `left join` to a `right join` and keep the same order of tables:

```
SELECT PhraseCategory.name, count(Phrase.*) AS qty
  FROM Phrase
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN PhraseCategory
    ON Phrase.CategoryId = PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId
 GROUP BY PhraseCategory.name
 ORDER BY PhraseCategory.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try IFNULL

```
SELECT PhraseCategory.name, IFNULL(count(*),0) AS qty
FROM Phrase
LEFT OUTER JOIN PhraseCategory
ON Phrase.CategoryId = PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId
GROUP BY PhraseCategory.name
ORDER BY PhraseCategory.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see counts for both phrases that do not have a category, and categories that do not have phrases, you can use a `full outer join.`

Since `Phrase.CategoryId` can be `null`, you might want to return a string instead of `null`, e.g. 'No Category'.

```
select 
   Category = coalesce(pc.name,'No Category')
 , qty = count(p.PhraseId)
from Phrase p 
  full outer join PhraseCategory pc 
    on p.CategoryId = pc.PhraseCategoryShortId
group by pc.name
order by pc.name;
```

returns:

```
+-------------+-----+
|  Category   | qty |
+-------------+-----+
| No Category |   1 |
| ColumnNames |   3 |
| Functions   |   0 |
| KeyWords    |   2 |
| Users       |   1 |
+-------------+-----+
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/FUBSY27286

```
insert into phrase (English, CategoryId) values
 ('who',null) /* no category */
,('select',1)
,('from',1)
,('PhraseId',2)
,('English',2)
,('CategoryId',2)
,('Anne',3);

insert into PhraseCategory (Name) values
 ('KeyWords')
,('ColumnNames')
,('Users')
,('Functions') /*no phrases */;
```